# Red5 general advice

Tags: red5

I am starting development on a project containing a web browser video streaming module.
I am seeking advice on whether a Red5 server will be useful or not required as I am new to the video streaming arena -

Users will upload video footage in all formats, .MOV .MPEG4 .AVI .WMV .MPEGPS .FLV .3GPP, and I need to allow other users to stream the videos youtube style (not live).

Thanks

Comment: I believe that this question does not ask a specific enough question. You did not include any code or elaborate on your intended use. This is way too broad and as such, I am voting to close it.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried to warn on the broad question by including the word 'general' in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red5 would be useful for this, but only certain media formats are supported for Video on demand VOD streaming. Any other formats would need to be transcoded into flv or mp4.